# Using UiAutomator on drop down list

Tags: android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

I'm exploring the UiAutomator capabilities on Android and I am trying to test it out along with the Google hangouts app. I've managed to go to the create new hangout page and enter a name, but I can't click on any of the drop down contacts as shown in the image below. I've tried searching by the package name `com.google.android.talk` and then using the `instance()` function, but I wasn't able to select the contacts. Is there anyway I could figure what the class name of that UI element would be? Or how else could I go about clicking that ui element?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this tool:

```
/home/gabriel/android/android-sdk/tools/uiautomatorviewer
```

Use it to navigate through the application's views and layouts.

Comment: I am using uiautomatorviewer and while I can browse the hierarchy and inspect controls, I can't inspect the elements of a dropdown list. uiautomatorviewer just doesn't let me click the dropdown list. Instead, it shows a blue rectangle around the element which is under the dropdownlist (which happens to be a webview for the app I am inspecting). I have tried uiautomatorviewer, hierarchyviewer as well as Appium Inspector and all three have the same problem. Is there any way to work around this?